# Optimization problem involving perimeter and area

Tags: calculus

[image]

I was able to do most of the question, up until it asked for a maximum and minimum for the total enclosed area.

I got two equations:

$4 = 4x + 2r\cdot\pi$

for the perimeter and,

$A = x_2 + \pi(r_2)$

for the area.

I isolated $r$ in the first equation plugged it into the second equation, isolating $x$. I rearranged it a bit to make it a little easier for myself and then took the derivative. Next, I set $\frac {dA}{dx}$ to $0$ to find my critical points. I happen to find that I had only one critical point which was $\frac 1{\pi +4}$.

I have no idea how to find the maximum and minimum from here on out. I know I could draw a sign diagram, but that would not help since I only have one critical point and the graph I got was linear, meaning it doesn't really have a max or min anyways. Did I just do my algebra wrong or did I do something else wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us your work for: "I isolated r in the first equation plugged it into the second equation, isolating x. I rearranged it a bit to make it a little easier for myself and then took the derivative. Next, I set dA\dx to 0 to find my critical points. I happen to find that I had only one critical point which was 1π+4."

Comment: @idk I isolated r in 4 = 4x + 2r*pi to get r = (4-4x)/2pi, then I subbed it into the second equation and A = x^2 + (16-8x+16x^2)/4pi. I took the derivative of that and got A' = 2x + (8x-2)/pi. I set A' as zero and got my CP value.

Comment: Which means $r=(2-2x)/\pi$

Comment: @idk If you don't already know, I edited my above comment as I pressed enter to earlier. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Let the length of the first piece be $x$, then the length of the second piece is $4-x$. The side of a square will be $x/4$ and the radius of circle will be $\frac{4-x}{2\pi}$. Thus, the area function will be the sum of areas of square and circle: $$A=\frac{x^2}{16}+\pi\cdot \frac{(4-x)^2}{4\pi^2}$$ Can you finish and find the maximum/minimum of $A(x)$, on the interval $0\le x \le 4$?

Comment: I calculated the derivative and got it simplified to A' = 4x + pi(x) -16. Solved for the CP and got x = 16/(4 +pi). I have one CP, so how do I find for both the maximum and minimum in this case then? There would only be one point where the slope changes, so what do I  here?

Comment: @BobSmith: The easiest way is to find $A(0)$, $A(4)$ and $A(16/(4+\pi))$: Then you'll see which one is minimum and which one is maximum. Remember, min or max can be reached on the boundaries of the interval. Another way is to analyze the sign of derivative before and after the CP.